# Is there a way to add terms for the Spell Checker in editor to reference?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

There are unique terms related to the industry that the spell checker might flag as incorrect.

We are looking for a solution for the client team to add the unique terms so they are not flagged as incorrect when spelt correctly and suggest this term for when it is spelt incorrectly.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the following modules:

[Wysiwyg SpellCheck](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_spellcheck)

> Wysiwyg SpellCheck module is a plugin for wysiwyg editor that enables TinyMCE spellchecker plugin.

[Spell Checker](https://www.drupal.org/project/spellchecker)

> This module supports spell checking of node content (including title, body and CCK fields).

Image from project page.

[image]

Comment: Spell Checker is for 6.x so far which I've written some time ago, but if there is enough interest, I'm happy to co-operate and migrate it towards 7.x.